# Office 2016 silent uninstall prompts: "Ready to uninstall?"

Tags: xml, deployment, office365, ms-office, silent

When trying to **silently** uninstall an Office Deployment the XML way, I get the following prompt:

[image: Office Prompt]

This is kind of annoying as I do not want our users (+/- 200) to see this prompt!

I am using the following command line:

```
setup.exe /configure remove.xml
```

The contents of my remove.xml are as follows:

```
<Configuration>
<Remove>
<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" NoCancel="yes" />
    <Product ID="VisioStdRetail">
    <Language ID="en-us" />
    <Language ID="nl-nl" />
    <Language ID="fr-fr" /> 
    </Product>
</Remove>
```

In this case, the remove.xml is only for Visio, but I have this problem for any product.
It just seems that Display Level="None" is not working the way I was expecting it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. :-)

Bert.